# How to update multiple instance fields within a DRF Serializer?

Tags: django, rest, serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework

In the DRF docs: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/#creating-a-serializer-class

It is shown how to update an existing instance using the `update` method. But the code that is shown is highly repetitive and has a DRY problem if the model is updated. How can the `validated_data` be passed into the `instance` once before then calling `save`?

```py
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update and return an existing `Snippet` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
        instance.code = validated_data.get('code', instance.code)
        instance.linenos = validated_data.get('linenos', instance.linenos)
        instance.language = validated_data.get('language', instance.language)
        instance.style = validated_data.get('style', instance.style)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [**`setattr()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr)

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    for key,value in validated_data.items():
        setattr(instance,key,value)
    instance.save()
    return instance
```